# Surefire tactical flashlight effective on sunglasses?

Tags: self-defense, weapons

I hear those super bright flashlights can blind the assailant for a few seconds, but how effective is such a flashlight if the assailant were wearing sunglasses?

Answer (score 4):

The [most recent reference I've found](http://www.technologyreview.com/news/408360/the-incapacitating-flashlight/), from 2007, indicates that tinted sunglasses may indeed block the effect, although it seems like the disorientation effect may still be effective.